# improve speed nested loops for pyomo constraint

Tags: constraints, nested-loops, pyomo, computation

I am trying to add this type of constraint "constraint1" to my Pyomo model by looping across a (symmetric) matrix of size "n" and performing a check, given the parameter a(i,j):

```
model.con1=ConstraintList()
for i in range(1,n):
    for j in range(1,i):
        if model.a[i,j]==1:
            model.con1.add((model.x[i] + model.x[j] )  <= 1 )
```

The code seems to work, but I would like to know if there is a more computationally efficient way to write the same.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following to see if it would work better:

```
model.n = RangeSet(n)
model.triangular = Set(within=model.n * model.n, filter=lambda i, j: j < i)

@model.Constraint(model.triangular)
def con(m, i, j):
    if model.a[i, j] == 1:
        return model.x[i] + model.x[j] <= 1
    else:
        return Constraint.Skip
```

Comment: It is not very clear if, in order to run it, I should just call the function . If I just use the code as it is, it runs faster, but the constraint seems ignored.

Comment: You should check to verify that `model.triangular.display()` has the elements you expect, and that `model.con.pprint()` has the correct form. This should do the same thing as the code that you have in your question, but I did not actually run it to test it.