# Improve pyomo constraint with nested loops

Tags: mathematical-optimization, pyomo, gurobi

I have a series of constraint that look like this:

```
def r7_encadenamiento_inicial(modelo,b, s, ss, l):
    condicion1 = modelo.s_index[s] < modelo.s_index[ss]
    if not condicion1:
       return pyo.Constraint.Skip
    condicion2 = (s,l) in modelo.S_L
    if not condicion2:
       return pyo.Constraint.Skip
    condicion3 = (ss,l) in modelo.S_L
    if condicion1 and condicion2 and condicion3:
       return modelo.x_s[b,s] >= modelo.x_s[b,ss] - 99*(2 - modelo.x[b,s] - 
       modelo.x[b,ss])
    else:
       return pyo.Constraint.Skip 
modelo.encadenamiento_inicial_r7 = pyo.Constraint(modelo.B, modelo.S, modelo.S, modelo.L, rule=r7_encadenamiento_inicial)
```

Is there a way to speed up? Just defining this constraint take more than 10 minutes..
(with cardinalities of 100,1000 and 50)

I have seen other question like this: [For loop in Pyomo Constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61469336/for-loop-in-pyomo-constraints) and [improve speed nested loops for pyomo constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449365/improve-speed-nested-loops-for-pyomo-constraint). But they were not much helpful..

Comment: It's not clear to me how your condition generalizes to much larger inputs (first condition is different from the other two, does this remain the same?). Please share more code.

Comment: That seems too long for the dimensionality you cite.  Can you update your post and show how each of these components are defined with some exemplar data?  Is `modelo.S` an ordered pyomo set?  etc.  Do you know how many instances of the constraint this creates?